# Set Deploy-mode to cluster for pyspark from jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, cloudera-cdh

I've installed a cloudera CDH cluster with spark2 on 7 hosts ( 2 matsers, 4 workers and 1 edge)

I installed a Jupyter server on the edge node, I want to set pyspark to run on cluster mode, I run this on a notebook

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']='--master yarn --deploy-mode=cluster pyspark-shell'

It gives me "Error: Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells."

Can someone helps me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is you can't. Firstly because the configured Jupiter behind the scenes launches a pyspark shell session. Which you cant run on cluster mode.

One soultion which i think of to your problem can be 
Livy+spark magic+jupyter

Where Livy can run on yarn mode and serve job request as REST calls.
Spark_magic residing on jupyter.

You can follow the below link for more info on this
https://blog.chezo.uno/livy-jupyter-notebook-sparkmagic-powerful-easy-notebook-for-data-scientist-a8b72345ea2d

Answer (score 0):

Major update.

I. Have succeeded to deploy a jupyter hub with cdh5.13,  it works without no problems.

One thing to pay attention to is to install as default language python 3, with python 2, multiple jobs will failed because of incompatibility with cloudera package